# How to loop inside a react const variable in the render method

Tags: reactjs

I have a mapped const variable which I use to inject to my return in the render method. My issue is now, the object I am mapping, has a collection of objects itself. I would like to loop through each one and add jsx syntax in. This is what I have:

```js
const tasks = this.state.tasks.map((task) => {
            var editable = this.state.editableTasks.filter(id => id === task.Id).length > 0;
            return (
               <li key={task.Id} className="list-group-item" style={{minHeight: '50px'}}>
                   <div className="pull-left" style={{width: '50%'}}>
                       {editable ? <input type="text" /> : <span>{task.Name}</span>}
                   </div>
                   <div className="pull-right" style={{marginTop: '-5px', width: '50%'}}>
                       <div className="pull-right">
                            <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={() => {this.AddSubTask(task.Id)}}>Add</button>
                            <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={() => { this.EditTask(task.Id)}}>{editable ? 'Save' : 'Edit'}</button>
                        </div>
                   </div>
               </li>
               
            //What I have currently tried:
            //for(var i = 0; i < task.SubTasks.length; i++) {
                //<ul>
                //<li>
                //...etc
                //</li>
                //</ul>
            //}

            //{task.SubTasks.map((subtask) => {
                //<ul>
                //<li>
                //...etc
                //</li>
                //</ul>
            //)};
            );
        });
        return (
          <div className="table-wrapper">
            <div className="task-container">
                <h3>{this.props.rowName}</h3>
            </div>
            <ul id="tasksContainer">
                {tasks}
                <li className="list-group-item list-group-item-last"><input type="button" value="Add Task" onClick={this.createTask.bind(this)} className="btn btn-success btn-override" /></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

      );
```

I do apologize for the formatting, couldn't quite get it right. Anyways, so in the const task = declaration, I would like to loop through each task.SubTasks (the collection OF the indexed collection) and add in another unordered list.

I have tried simply writing a for loop but it didn't work, and also trying to write another mapped function, which didn't work either. Is this doable?

Comment: `this` contexts are different in `map`.

Comment: @AndrewL.I don't think that's OPs problem cuz he's using arrows.

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what your intended solution is here.. can you be more specific? also let's use the terms array and object separately.. "you map the `tasks` array, which has a `task` object... which also has an inner array you want to turn into jsx? can you show us what you tried?

Comment: My tasks **array** has an child **array** which I am trying to iterate through in my declaration. I did mention what I tried, but just for principle, I'll go ahead and add the code itself.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mean to down vote this! I must have accidentally hit the button, but now it won't let me undo it. 

Comment: You could upvote it to undo it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another map should work.. the for loop *could* work if you create an empty array first and push components to it.

```
const subTaskComponents = []
for (var i = 0; i < task.SubTasks.length; i++) {
  subTaskComponents.push(
    <ul key={task.SubTasks[i].id>
      <li>..</li>
    </ul>
  )
}
```

`map` is a nicer solution though

```
const subTaskComponents = task.SubTasks.map(subTask =>
  <ul key={subTask.id}>
    <li>..</li>
  </ul>
)
```

Then in either case you can use it the same way you have with `tasks` inside render:

```
render() {
  const tasks = this.state.tasks.map((task) => {
    const subTaskComponents = task.SubTasks.map(subTask =>
      <ul key={subTask.id}>
        <li>..</li>
      </ul>
    )

    return (
      <div>{subTaskComponents}</div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>{tasks}</div>
  )
}
```