# Assign a const variable inside a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactivesearch

I'm using Reactivesearch, and I'm trying to assign a const variable inside a map function. Specifically in the `.map` Like such:

```
onAllData(data, streamData) {

    return (
        <div className="grid">
        {
            data.map((item) => 
                const propertyName = item.productName;

                <div className="flex-container card" key={item._id}>
                    <div className="content">
                        <p>{propertyName}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    );
}
```

`const propertyName = item.productName;` is giving me problem. `Error states unexpected token` .

Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering an array.map() in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282997/rendering-an-array-map-in-react) and [How to loop inside a react const variable in the render method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886262) and [Putting a variable inside render() return - React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50449877)

Comment: If your function has multiple statements your function needs a body: `x=>{x+1;return 22}`, instead of `x=>22`. You could simply do the following: `data.map(({propertyName,id})=><div ... `

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You need to go from expression syntax to the block syntax, using braces and `return`:

```
        data.map((item) => {
            const propertyName = item.productName;

            return (<div className="flex-container card" key={item._id}>
                <div className="content">
                    <p>{propertyName}</p>
                </div>
            </div>)
        })
```

However, you could also use destructuring to get your `propertyName`, and then you are back to one expression:

```
        data.map(({productName, _id}) =>
           <div className="flex-container card" key={_id}>
                <div className="content">
                    <p>{propertyName}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
```

Answer (score 3):

That is an improper use of arrow functions.

Fix:

```
data.map(({productName, _id}) => (
   <div className="flex-container card" key={_id}>
       <div className="content">
            <p>{productName}</p>
        </div>
   </div>
);
```